# xml.etree get tag which has a child with specific attribute

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I have the following xml file:

```
<node id="1416646243" />
<node id="1416646244">
    <tag k="crossing" v="unregulated" />
</node>
<node id="1416646245">
    <tag k="crossing" v="traffic_signals" />
</node>
```

I want to select the `<node>` tag which contains a `<tag>` tag with attribute `v="traffic_signals"`.
However if I use the following code, I get the `<tag>` tag in return.

`root.find('.//node/tag[@v="traffic_signals"]')`

And as far as i know, `xml.etree`  doesn't provide a way to get parent.

How can I actually get the `node` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Not very eficcient - but it works

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r>
<node id="1416646243" />
<node id="1416646244">
    <tag k="crossing" v="unregulated" />
</node>
<node id="1416646245">
    <tag k="crossing" v="traffic_signals" />
</node>
</r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
node = [n for n in root.findall('.node') if n.find('tag[@v="traffic_signals"]') is not None][0]
print(node.attrib)
```

output

```
{'id': '1416646245'}
```

Comment: Yes, this is my current implementation. I hoped i could avoid what is essentially nested cycles though.

Comment: Can you use lxml?

Comment: I can but i don't see how it helps as xpath support is the same as in xml.etree. At least the expression from the answer above doesn't work either.

Comment: I think in lxml you can find the child and navigate to parent.

Comment: Indeed you can! Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Here your solution, you can check element with sub-element inside "//parent[./direct_child]" or "//parent[.//children_of_child]" result element will be the parent

```
root.find('.//node[./tag[@v="traffic_signals"]]')
```

Comment: This results in `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`. I'm afraid that's because xml.etree doesn't support full xpath syntax. Is there maybe a good alternative library which does?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky, but you can use `..` to go back up to the parent after matching the child.

```
root.find('.//node/tag[@v="traffic_signals"]/..')
```